# perl mktemp and echo

Tags: perl, command-line, temp

i am trying to put some word in tempfile via commandline
temp file creat but word not past in tempfile

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
system ('clear');
$TMPFILE = "mktemp /tmp/myfile/devid.XXXXXXXXXX";
$echo = "echo /"hello world/" >$TMPFILE";
system ("$TMPFILE");
system ("$echo");
```

Please Help to Solve This

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To capture the name output by mktemp, do this instead:

```
chomp($TMPFILE = `mktemp /tmp/myfile/devid.XXXXXXXXXX`);
```

But Perl can do all the things you are doing without resorting to the shell.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid using external commands from perl script as much as possible.

you can use: `File::Temp` module in this case, see [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a specific demonstration of the advice that others have given you: where possible, use Perl directly rather than invoking `system`. Also, you should get in the habit of including `use strict` and `use warnings` in your Perl scripts.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Temp;
my $ft = File::Temp->new(
    UNLINK   => 0,
    TEMPLATE => '/tmp/myfile/devid.XXXXXXXXXX',
);

print "Writing to temp file: ", $ft->filename, "\n";

print $ft "Hello, world.\n";
```

Comment: you import tempfile but don't use it